# Ggplot2 muestra mes incorrecto

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
df <- structure(list(Month = structure(1:12, .Label = c("2021-01-31", "2021-02-28", "2021-03-31", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-31", "2021-06-30", "2012-01-31", "2012-02-29", "2012-03-31", "2012-04-30", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-30"), class = "factor"), AvgVisits = c(6.98655104580674,7.66045407330464, 7.69761337479304, 7.54387561322994, 7.24483848458728, 6.32001400498928, 6.66794871794872, 7.207780853854, 7.60281201431308, 6.70113837397123, 6.57634103019538, 6.75321935568936)), .Names = c("Month","AvgVisits"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

df$Month <- as.Date(df$Month)
```

Utilizo el siguiente codigo para hacer un grafico que debería iniciar desde Enero, pero inicia en Febrero

```
df %>% 
  filter(Month>as.Date("2021-01-01")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=AvgVisits))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y")
```

[image: Grafico que obtengo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin duda es confuso, pero no es ninguna falla de `ggplot`. Lo que ocurre es que tienes un `geom_col()` y en el eje x una escala continua, el "tick" o la rayita con la etiqueta se coloca en el medio de cada barra, por ejemplo, si tu primer fecha es "2021-01-31" y la segunda "2021-02-28", el "tick" aparecerá en el medio, y cae justamente a mitad de febrero.

Lo que puedes hacer es directamente darle una etiqueta al `factor` `Month` que se corresponda con el mes:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Month>as.Date("2021-01-01")) %>% 
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, labels=format(Month,"%b-%Y"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=AvgVisits)) +
  geom_col()
```